# How can I create a bootable iso from an extracted Ubuntu 13.04 iso?

Tags: boot, live-cd, iso

I have an extracted copy of Ubuntu 13.04 iso (live CD), but if I burn it directly it will not boot. Is there any way to create a bootable iso so that I can burn it to a DVD or USB flash drive?

I tried ISO Master, but it first wanted an iso and allows me to add some more files. Can I use it to create iso only from extracted folders?

Comment: check the commands her: http://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso The 1st part is about extracting an ISO but at the end it also shows how to create the ISO (and if needed how to create the new checksum).

Comment: you can use uNetBootloader for making pendrive bootable in ubuntu it is available in ubuntu soft

Answer (score 4):

**An ISO if extracted, will loose it's capability to boot. Building ISO from this extracted files need to done in a special manner to set booting flag and other parameter**

You just point your burning software to ISO (not extracted) , then the dvd/cd will be bootable.

If you want to customize ubuntu ISO, please see [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48535/35775)

To rebuilt from folder content, you can do so using powerISO (if on windows). [Here is tutorial that may help you.](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/make-bootable-cd.htm). This option should be available with all standard burning software. Just check the manual.

Comment: but i have only extracted folder.

Comment: and i want to re-create bootable iso for that folder not CD/DVD

Comment: didn't understand, you want to recreate a boot able ISO from a folder? You are trying to change anything or you have just deleted the ISO after extraction and want to rebuild the ISO

Comment: yes i only wan't to rebuild extracted iso, without any changes. i have deleted iso by mistake.

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: i'm on ubuntu 13.04 but xp is available on my old machine.

Comment: I don't understand what "An ISO if extracted, will the bootable property. So it will never boot unless you manually set booting flag and other parameter" means. It is bootable or not? The name "bootable" is confusing, isn't it "unbootable" rather?

Comment: But upvoted for the PowerISO tuto, that's the only answer that really answers the user question until now.

Answer (score 4):

To make an ISO from files on your hard drive, you can use the mkisofs command.  To use it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
mkisofs -o /home/user/Desktop/test/Ubuntu.iso /home/user/Desktop/test
```

(Using the command above, I have a folder called test in the Desktop folder, which will create the ISO in the same test folder, using only the files in the test folder).

Once created, then you can burn it to a DVD.

**Note**: This will not create a bootable DVD.  To create a bootable DVD you need to get [ISOLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX), and you still can use mkisofs.

Comment: yes, but i want to make bootable iso. so i can burn it on DVD or make a bootable usb stick. are you sure it make bootable iso.

Comment: I'm testing right now, and I'll let you know shortly.

Comment: I'm testing iso in virtual box and it says boot device not found.

Comment: See the note that I added in the answer.

Comment: How can we make the ISO bootable for use in VM?

Comment: @Justech You need mkisofs to generate the new iso and specify boot information.

Answer (score 0):

The best option i can think of is to download Poweriso and extract it straight to the dvd. It should already be bootable after that. Did u delete the original iso and all you have is the extracted version? Sorry the only way i know is to have the iso, im not sure how if it is already extracted.

Comment: yes i only have an extracted folder of iso.

Comment: I really doubt that only extracting make it bootable, and the folders are already extracted here, so the user cannot extract anything.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has grub installed, you do not need a DVD/usb to boot.

Put your `iso` in the hard disk and modify the grub menu; this also lets you boot from an `iso`.

Why do you need to extract files from the `iso`?

Comment: I doubt of this answer. Grub doesn't make an unbootable ISO bootable. It makes nothing bootable by itself, it make the action of booting that is bootable, that's all. The bootable/unbootable is a property of the files.

Answer (score 0):

I use (http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - been using it for years to burn iso's to usb. To create an ISO file:

Open Terminal. Navigate to the directory you want to create the ISO in. then:

```
mkisofs –o thefilename.iso /home/thepath/2/thefolder/ofthe/extractedfiles
```

Comment: The files are already extracted! It's not an ISO, the user wants to create an ISO!

Comment: ISO master is a great tool, but, as far as I know, knows only how to deal with  .nrg eand mdf. files. I doubt there is only that kind of files in their extracted ISO.

Comment: good point @Quidam   - let me edit my answer to a more native solution

Comment: though i believe it may be a redundant answer.. haha

Answer (score 0):

Web-E already gave a very good answer with the [PowerISO](https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/make-bootable-iso.htm) tutorial.

As an alternative solution, I've found an interesting answer there:
https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-re-create-a-bootable-iso-from-extracted-windows-installation-files

It's for Windows, but as this solution is very easy, it probably worths creating a small Windows booting disk, or use the mini XP Windows included in Hiren's boot live CD. I don't know if it's feasible, it has to be tested to answer this question, but the software used here, [imgburn](https://www.imgburn.com/) is compatible XP.

Considering you didn't touch anything in your files or folders of your extracted ISO, as it's obvious you cannot create bootable ISO from any kind of files or folder (bootable files that will pass important info to the bootloader are needed).

In the example, they use ImgBurn (Windows) with "create image files from files or folders". Ignore the parts regarding Windows files (like ei.cfg) as we aren't trying to make a bootable Windows.

They turned a bunch of .dll files and other formats, to an ISO file, and checked “Make Image Bootable“ in the section called Advanced → Bootable Disc.

So, it's exactly what you want to do, turning a bunch of files and folders, with any formats, to an ISO, and giving the ISO the instrinsic "bootable" property.

Once again, it won't be bootable if the ISO from which you extracted the files wasn't already a bootable OS type.

There are other software able to do the same: 
[Winiso](https://www.winiso.com/support/tutorials/burn-bootable-iso.html) (their tuto is badly explained, but we see on the image that they used files and folders to construct their bootable ISO),

Additional hints:

Alternatively, if everything fails, software like [AnytoISO](https://crystalidea.com/anytoiso) to create an ISO from any kind of files, and using another sofware to make the ISO bootable, it can be made [from the command line](https://www.tecmint.com/create-an-iso-from-a-bootable-usb-in-linux/), or from a software.

*One way to **check** if your extracted folders are able to boot* is to extract the bootable file from it. They use UltraISO for that [here](http://bootableusb.net/make-non-bootable-iso-image-bootable/),  “Bootable > Extract Boot File from CD/DVD”.
I didn't test, but I imagine that if there's not boot-file in your folders, it may return an error message.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is to use Linux Live USB Creator to boot your USB from ubuntu .iso file.
you can download the .exe file from [here](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download/) and if you want to use it in ubuntu, I thimk you can run it with [wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/)

Comment: I think it's out of topic, it's files, not an ISO.