# kickstart install ubuntu 14.04 LTS without intervention and no swap

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, swap, automation, kickstart

Thanks for [previous questions about automatic installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516687/how-do-i-make-a-custom-ubuntu-iso-for-fully-offline-installations), but I am running into an issue doing an automatic install without getting a swap partition.

Here is my `ks.cfg`:

```
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=AMD64 or Intel EM64T

#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone --utc UTC
#Root password
rootpw --disabled
#Initial user
user deleteme [...]
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
#Disk partitioning information
part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow --asprimary 
part swap --size 100
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled 
#Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
#Install these packages
%packages
openssh-server
# After system is installed, remove the apt.conf file with debproxy defined.
%post
rm -rf /etc/apt/apt.conf
%end
```

Commenting out the `part swap --size 100` line causes the installer to complain and create a prompt.  I've tried setting the size to `0` but that causes another issue that causes many prompts.  Is there a way to get rid of swap and not get silly prompts?

Comment: Maybe set swap to 1?

Comment: Maybe you should create separate partitions for boot, swap and root (in that order). You are using --grow for / and my guess is that / is filling up disk and there is not room for swap. My hint would be part `part /boot --fstype ext4 --size 1024 --asprimary` for boot, `part swap --size 100 --asprimary` for swap (is 100MB enough for swap ?) and after that  `part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow --asprimary` for root which will fill up remaining space.

Comment: `part swap --size 100` "works" in the sense that it doesn't produce an error, but I'm still left with swap space I'd rather not have.  A coworker suggested removing it in `%post` which I'll try today.