# Want to build my own Ubuntu from source code

Tags: 12.04, compiling, source-code

I have two requirements

1. I want whole Ubuntu 12.04 Source code.
2. I want to compile it.

Can you please tell me about from where I can get the source code and what tool I will need to compile it? From 30000 feet, it might look stupid but I really need this.

Thanks for your support...

Regards

Comment: There is nothing like "Ubuntu source" or any "OS source", you can get the source code of every individual element Ubuntu is composed starting from the kernel itself.

Comment: You are basically asking how to create your own Ubuntu. That is possible with http://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso/409651#409651 This is a method where you take a server version (so no desktop) and add in packages to create your own system. Another one with a desktop can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Thank you @Rinzwind for your prompt response. The link is definitely interesting.
However, it raises one more question in my mind. The question is that kickstart is allowing me to only add/delete some specific package from available pool of packages.What if I want to add my own written package to it?
Actually, I have customize upstart library and I want to integrate that library into my Ubuntu. Can I do this by following your link?
Thanks again for your help.... I really appreciate it...

Comment: That is also possible. You can add packages to any system manually and add those files to the kickstart file yourself. There is a cache directory on the disc where you put your own files.

Comment: Hi @Rinzwind !
I follow the instructions shared by you and everything went really smooth. I really can't appreciate enough. Thanks for the link :).
I have still one confusion. How can I replace existing package (upstart) with my own updated package? From internet search, I have an impression that I can remove the package from "newIso/pool/main/u/upstart" and replace it with my own package. But I am not sure about this.
Information is given in last section of "http://kickstart-tools.sourceforge.net/howkickstartworks.html#makinguseof"

Can you please guide me? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That should be the correct method yes. Delete the original from the pool and add the package you want. The system will install all packages that are in the pool so that should be all you need to do. Do keep in mind that kickstart is redhat software that is supported in Ubuntu -but- not 100%. It might be smarter to take the manual route (and mount the iso, and copy it over to the iso yourself).