# Creating LXC container using iso file

Tags: 12.04, iso, lxc

Is it possible to create an LXC container from iso file? Following points might give you better context about what I want

- I have created my own distro by following "[How to create customized ubuntu servier iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso/409651#409651)".
- I now have an iso file which I want to use as an LXC template.

Is there any way to do so? Thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: Have you managed to get it running? Here are some hints on it:
https://serverfault.com/questions/843525/how-to-build-a-custom-lxd-image-from-install-iso