# How do I add extra packages for an offline install of server?

Tags: server, system-installation, package-management, offline

I've been following this guide and everything has worked great EXCEPT for the offline packages part: [How to create a Customized Ubuntu Server ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso). Basically, I need to add a set of packages into the iso and have them install with an offline installer cd.

At the "Select and install software" portion of the install, I get an error saying there was an issue, with no supporting logs or evidence. I don't know how to troubleshoot this or figure out if there is a log I can look at somewhere (didn't think so for an iso).

However, I ***do know*** the issue is caused by this line in my seed file:

```
d-i pkgsel/include string flex
```

My cd/dists/precise/extras/binary-i386/Packages file contains:

```
Package: flex
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 496
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Manoj Srivastava <srivasta@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.5.35-10ubuntu3
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11), m4, libfl-dev (= 2.5.35-10ubuntu3), dpkg (>= 1.15.4) | install-info
Pre-Depends: debconf | debconf-2.0
Recommends: gcc | c-compiler
Suggests: bison, build-essential
Filename: ./pool/extras/flex_2.5.35-10ubuntu3_amd64.deb
Size: 231700
MD5sum: 2d463f7d5de9b4babc08863d9000348c
SHA1: 7a9b2183f7365dcb4c00322164aef47ffd20356f
SHA256: 59196b17e82ebc5fb86c3c9a66bcdf0c7691e2db0728441738f820cce362dea6
SHA512: 742aa993eef9cbc3b686adf692af850248fe675e405e8dc45c4168c44ee0c2ff3efdadee7ec536c158bbea198be1db412b195b1d7f191eecab70b57aef779d28
Description: A fast lexical analyzer generator.
 Flex is a tool for generating scanners: programs which recognized lexical
 patterns in text. It reads the given input files for a description of a
 scanner to generate. The description is in the form of pairs of regular
 expressions and C code, called rules. Flex generates as output a C source
 file, lex.yy.c, which defines a routine yylex().  This file is compiled
 and linked with the -lfl library to produce an executable. When the
 executable is run, it analyzes its input for occurrences of the regular
 expressions. Whenever it finds one, it executes the corresponding C code.
Multi-Arch: foreign
Homepage: http://flex.sf.net/
```

My cd/pool/extras/ folder contains all of the .debs.

My only thoughts so far are that dependencies are an issue, or that becuase my server is amd64 that the i386 piece is causing an issue. Possibly even the md5sums.txt I generated is wrong and can cause errors?

Anyone have any idea of what the issue may be here? If not, what are some baseline things I can do to get a very basic offline package working?

Comment: I've found my problem. I saved the debug logs to /tmp and then opened a shell to cat syslog that was in /tmp. The problem was unmet dependencies. Holy crap. Do I need to get every single dependency ready before I install all of these things? Is there an easy way to download the dependencies?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It seems you have found a solution to your problem. Once you reach a reputation of 15, go ahead and [answer your own question](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to add **d-i pkgsel/include string flex** ? As far as I know, this command is added if you want to download from repository.
For unmet dependecy problem , you can install deb package in new-installed VM and copy /var/apt/cache or you just clear /var/apt/cache the install deb package.

Comment: This answer is quite unclear to me. Please avoid answers that lead to questions by the OP. Rather try to be clear and describe step by step how the OP can solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-rdepends flex` will show the dependency