# Is there an easy way to determine what dependencies of dependencies I'll need to install for a custom server ISO?

Tags: server, dependencies, iso, customization

I'm installing packages into my custom ubuntu server ISO for a complete offline install via this guide: [How to create a Customized Ubuntu Server ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso). The only option for the install is a single dvd. No way to plug in a usb or connect to the internet to install packages. Must be able to put the dvd in, install and that's it - good to go.

Everything works great except when the initial install tries to install these extra packages... it breaks on unmet dependencies *for the dependencies* of these packages.

**Example:**

extra package I'm installing during initial system install -> its dependencies -> dependencies for those dependencies - **BREAKS HERE** -

This wouldn't be an issue if I knew which ones I needed to download ahead of time to put onto the iso! However, I cannot tell which ones will be needed until I load the dvd up and try to actually do the install and watch if it breaks.

There must be an easier way to do this... right? I'm already downloading all first level dependencies needed just in case. Should I extend that out one more level?

Comment: ehm apt-get can show you dependencies. why not use it? And getting the ISO to fit on a CD is going to be difficult. A DVD would be smarter.

Comment: Well, I already am. I'm using apt-cache depends on the main packages, then downloading all of those dependencies. However, the problem comes at the dependencies of those dependencies (see example). There's a lot but only SOME are breaking the install if they are missing. I have no idea which ones matter or not at that level. I have no idea which ones I need to download, and there are a ton to check.

And yeah, I meant dvd.

Comment: Yeah... I suppose that can work. It just felt very band-aidy. Thought there might be a more official way. Thanks!

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow, have to finish some stuff tonight...

Comment: Thanks guys. Figured I was missing something. Else I know I can't be the only one with this problem.

Comment: Just realized you made the other thread Rinzwind. Double thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with ...

```
 sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends
```

Example on "apache":

```
$ apt-rdepends apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2
  Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.12-2ubuntu2)
  Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.12-2ubuntu2)
  Depends: apache2-utils (>= 2.4)
  Depends: lsb-base
  Depends: mime-support
  Depends: perl
  Depends: procps
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.14)
apache2-bin
  Depends: libapr1 (>= 1.5.0)
  Depends: libaprutil1 (>= 1.5.0)
  Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-freetds
  Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-mysql
  Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-odbc
  Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql
  Depends: libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  Depends: libaprutil1-ldap
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7)
  Depends: liblua5.1-0
  Depends: libpcre3
  Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3)
  Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4)
  Depends: perl
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
libapr1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16)
libc6
  Depends: libgcc1
libgcc1
  Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
gcc-5-base
libuuid1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: passwd
passwd
  Depends: debianutils (>= 2.15.2)
  Depends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libpam-modules
  Depends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1)
  Depends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
  Depends: libsemanage1 (>= 2.0.3)
debianutils
  Depends: sensible-utils
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
sensible-utils
libaudit1
  Depends: libaudit-common (>= 1:2.4.2-1ubuntu1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libaudit-common
libpam-modules
  PreDepends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  PreDepends: debconf-2.0
  PreDepends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  PreDepends: libdb5.3
  PreDepends: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.1.8-3.1ubuntu3)
  PreDepends: libpam0g (>= 1.1.3-2)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 2.1.9)
debconf
  PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4)
perl-base
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.17)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
dpkg
  PreDepends: libbz2-1.0
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 2.3)
  PreDepends: tar (>= 1.23)
  PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
liblzma5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
multiarch-support
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-2)
libselinux1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libpcre3
libpcre3
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
tar
  PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
libacl1
  Depends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-8)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libattr1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
zlib1g
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
debconf-2.0
libdb5.3
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
libpam-modules-bin
  Depends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1)
  Depends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
libpam0g
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  Depends: debconf-2.0
  Depends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libsemanage1
  Depends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1)
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libselinux1 (>= 2.1.12)
  Depends: libsemanage-common (= 2.3-1build2)
  Depends: libsepol1 (>= 2.1.4)
  Depends: libustr-1.0-1 (>= 1.0.4)
libsemanage-common
libsepol1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libustr-1.0-1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libaprutil1
  Depends: libapr1 (>= 1.4.8-2~)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libdb5.3
  Depends: libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1)
  Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libexpat1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libssl1.0.0
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  Depends: debconf-2.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libaprutil1-dbd-freetds
libaprutil1-dbd-mysql
  Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.5.4-1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1)
libmysqlclient18
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1)
  Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libstdc++6
  Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.2.1-22ubuntu2)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.18)
  Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)
mysql-common
libaprutil1-dbd-odbc
  Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.5.4-1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.1)
libodbc1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libltdl7 (>= 2.4.2)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libltdl7
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql
  Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.5.4-1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libpq5
libpq5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~)
  Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7)
  Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0)
libgssapi-krb5-2
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libcomerr2 (>= 1.34)
  Depends: libk5crypto3 (>= 1.8+dfsg)
  Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-2)
  Depends: libkrb5support0 (>= 1.13~alpha1+dfsg)
libcomerr2
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libk5crypto3
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libkrb5support0 (>= 1.13~alpha1+dfsg)
libkrb5support0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libkrb5-3
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16)
  Depends: libcomerr2 (>= 1.34)
  Depends: libk5crypto3 (>= 1.9+dfsg~beta1)
  Depends: libkeyutils1 (>= 1.5.9)
  Depends: libkrb5support0 (= 1.13.2+dfsg-2)
libkeyutils1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libldap-2.4-2
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libgnutls-deb0-28 (>= 3.3.9)
  Depends: libgssapi3-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libsasl2-2
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libgnutls-deb0-28
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  Depends: libgmp10 (>= 2:6)
  Depends: libhogweed4
  Depends: libnettle6
  Depends: libp11-kit0 (>= 0.20.7)
  Depends: libtasn1-6 (>= 4.3-0)
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
libgmp10
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libhogweed4
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libgmp10 (>= 2:6.0.0)
  Depends: libnettle6 (= 3.1.1-4)
libnettle6
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libp11-kit0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16)
  Depends: libffi6 (>= 3.0.4)
libffi6
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libtasn1-6
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libgssapi3-heimdal
  Depends: libasn1-8-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libcomerr2 (>= 1.01)
  Depends: libhcrypto4-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libheimntlm0-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libkrb5-26-heimdal (>= 1.6~git20131117)
  Depends: libroken18-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
libasn1-8-heimdal
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libcomerr2 (>= 1.01)
  Depends: libroken18-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
libroken18-heimdal
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
libhcrypto4-heimdal
  Depends: libasn1-8-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libroken18-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
libheimntlm0-heimdal
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: libhcrypto4-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libkrb5-26-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libroken18-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
libkrb5-26-heimdal
  Depends: libasn1-8-heimdal (>= 1.6~git20131117)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libcomerr2 (>= 1.41.11)
  Depends: libhcrypto4-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libheimbase1-heimdal (>= 1.6~git20131117)
  Depends: libhx509-5-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libroken18-heimdal (>= 1.6~git20131117)
  Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9)
  Depends: libwind0-heimdal (>= 1.6~git20120311)
libheimbase1-heimdal
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libhx509-5-heimdal
  Depends: libasn1-8-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libcomerr2 (>= 1.34)
  Depends: libhcrypto4-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libheimbase1-heimdal (>= 1.6~git20131117)
  Depends: libroken18-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
  Depends: libwind0-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
libwind0-heimdal
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libcomerr2 (>= 1.01)
  Depends: libroken18-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226)
libsqlite3-0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libsasl2-2
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libsasl2-modules-db (>= 2.1.26.dfsg1-14)
libsasl2-modules-db
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libdb5.3
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.5.4-1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9)
libaprutil1-ldap
  Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.5.4-1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7)
liblua5.1-0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1)
libxml2
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~)
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3)
libicu55
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)
perl
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libdb5.3
  Depends: libgdbm3 (>= 1.8.3)
  Depends: perl-base (= 5.20.2-6)
  Depends: perl-modules (>= 5.20.2-6)
  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.2.3)
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.17)
libgdbm3
  Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4)
  Depends: install-info
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
install-info
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1)
perl-modules
  Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.2-1)
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.17.17)
apache2-data
apache2-utils
  Depends: libapr1 (>= 1.4.8-2~)
  Depends: libaprutil1 (>= 1.5.0)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1)
lsb-base
mime-support
procps
  Depends: initscripts
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libncurses5 (>= 5.5-5~)
  Depends: libncursesw5 (>= 5.6+20070908)
  Depends: libprocps3
  Depends: libtinfo5
  Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7)
initscripts
  Depends: coreutils (>= 5.93)
  Depends: debianutils (>= 4)
  Depends: file-rc
  Depends: lsb-base (>= 3.2-14)
  Depends: mount (>= 2.11x-1)
  Depends: sysv-rc
  Depends: sysvinit-utils (>= 2.88dsf-50)
coreutils
  PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8)
  PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-8)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 2.1.13)
file-rc
mount
  PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.17.2)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.25)
  PreDepends: libsmartcols1 (>= 2.25)
  PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183)
libblkid1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  Depends: libuuid1 (>= 2.16)
libmount1
  Depends: libblkid1 (>= 2.17.2)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
  Depends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
libsmartcols1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17)
libudev1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16)
sysv-rc
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  Depends: debconf-2.0
  Depends: insserv (>> 1.12.0-10)
  Depends: sysvinit-utils (>= 2.86.ds1-62)
insserv
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
sysvinit-utils
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
libncurses5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libtinfo5 (= 5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1)
libtinfo5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
libncursesw5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: libtinfo5 (= 5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1)
libprocps3
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
 ~$
```

and ... damn what a long list _O-

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Is this what people who make their own custom versions of linux always run into? Want to make sure I'm not making this harder on myself than it needs to be.

Comment: Nope. If you create your own system as if you want your ISO to be you can then copy the archive over of the DEBs you downloaded for your own system into your chroot. Basically you let your system fix the dependencies  ;-) Same can be done with gsettings (export from system and import in chroot) ;-)

Comment: Above works best if both systems are the same version of course

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand upon the chroot stuff? This is news to me. How does it differ from your guide I've been following? I take it internet is required for dependency fixing.

Comment: Oh the act of creating a part on your disk where you can edit your ISO is a "chroot". When you do an "apt-get" in a chroot it will add the packages to your "to install" packages of your new system. It is in the guide ;-) By the way: find my "server" version ... it is probably the easiest one to alter since it has no desktop too (and you can really build it from scratch)