# How to change display settings and gnome tweak tool settings by using terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu. I want to build a custom Ubuntu image (ISO) with Cubic Builder. But Cubic allows me to change things only by terminal (not creating Live Cd ISO).
So what do i type in terminal to change the desktop background, change appeareance of GNOME Desktop, make it look like macOS. 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked for any commands?  A search came up with multiple choices in the top answers (eg. first in startpage was https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity/510135). Yes it says Unity, but for what you want the are [almost] identical (differing primarily in version of GTK+ or gimp+gnome.toolkit).

Comment: For customizing the background, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149017/how-to-customise-gnome-default-background-and-lock-screen-image/1149151#1149151. Other settings can also be changed in a similar way. you just have to use the correct gsettings key and value.

Comment: Here is a more comprehensive answer, explaining how to change other settings: https://askubuntu.com/a/1091591/100356