# Customization of LiveCDs Wallpaper, Keyboard Layout, Network adapter drivers and fix screen resolution

Tags: drivers, keyboard-layout, live-cd, customization, desktop-background

I followed instructions of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization to customize my first LiveCD based on *ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso* (note that all URI references point to chapters of that tutorial).
After testing the result, I found some things where my customization seems not to have worked:

1. Change the **desktop background to custom PNG**: Eventhough I added my wallpaper to */usr/share/backgrounds/* and modified */usr/share/gnome-background-properties/ubuntu-wallpapers.xml* to point to my wallpaper instead of *warty-final-ubuntu.png*, the wallpaper is still the *warty-final-ubuntu.png*. The instructions say that I should modify some more files ([see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Custom_Background_for_GNOME)) but I could not find those.
2. Change the **keyboard layout to QWERTZ**: In the instructions there was a section about localization ([see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Setting_regional_defaults)). I couldn't find */usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/misc.py* (probably since I uninstalled ubiquity before) to customize the layout.
   Am I required to have ubiquity installed in order to preset the keyboard layout? I uninstalled it since I plan to use the created LiveCD only as boot medium and not for installing Ubuntu to any computer.
   Furthermore, I did not follow the instructions regarding [UEFI boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#UEFI) since I already failed executing the first command 
   `sed -i '6i    loadfont /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2' boot/grub/grub.cfg` .
   Am I required to execute the script to make my LiveCD work properly? What exactly am I customizing here?
3. Inappropriate **screen size**: When testing the created ISO with VirtualBox, only a **small 800x600** screen is displayed. When starting via the most recent Ubuntu LTS LiveCD, I do not encounter this fixed resolution.
   Is this also related to the CD customization and how can I investigate where this issue comes from?
4. I skipped the complete **[Advanced Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Rebuilding_initrd)** step. This step is not required at all if I don't want to change anything here, right?
5. **Cleanup process**: In the [cleanup section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Cleanup), the manual says, after installing software, I should execute: `rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id` and `rm /sbin/initctl` followed by
   `dpkg-divert --rename --remove /sbin/initctl` .
   Do I have to run these commands only if I installed new software or also when doing an apt upgrade (this may also install new packages, right?)?
6. **Find, install and test specific network drivers**: Since my host system is not an Ubuntu OS, I did the customization in a VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest system. I know from the past, that the network adapter of my computer may not be recognized when booting the physical machine with an Ubuntu LiveCD.
   I'm just wondering how I can find out whether this problem is still present without burning the CD.
   Is it possible from VirtualBox, to delegate the network resource as-is to the guest system for testing whether I need additional drivers?
   And how can I find out which drivers I may need to install?
   As soon as I know what to install, can I just run apt install in the chroot environment to install the drivers as done in the APT section of the tutorial [see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Apt)?

Since I'm not that familiar with Ubuntu yet, I would appreciate if your answers contain the instructions what I should to as well as a rough explanation what the instructions are for.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: for your point no. 1 https://askubuntu.com/q/1149017/739431

Comment: Following the post you're referring helped me solving the point no. 1. Thank you!