# How can I install VLC without libdvdcss?

Tags: 14.04, vlc

My company is in a position where we need to distribute VLC on our Ubuntu 14.04 image. How can I install VLC without libdvdcss, or, how can I remove the libdvdcss bits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Customized Ubuntu Server ISO?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso)

Comment: Or dupe of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd?lq=1

Comment: @AndroidDev No. This just seeks to install `vlc` without the dependency on `libdvdcss2`

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing to remove, the only connection between `vlc` packages and `libdvdcss2` is that `vlc-nox` suggests `libdvdcss2` (which is a very weak dependency — made necessary by the fact that the standard repositories don't carry `libdvdcss2`). It's perfectly possible to install `vlc` without `libdvdcss2` as is.