# Creating ISO images from already installed Ubuntu Server on commandline

Tags: 14.04, server, iso

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. I need to make an .ISO  image from it. The trouble is that all tools i have come across use GUI. Ubuntu Server on the other hand does not come with GUI.

Are there ways of creating an ISO image from an already installed Ubuntu OS on command line?

Comment: Don't. If this is about just adding software to an installation: use a live dvd to chroot it and copy the DEB's in the "/var/cache/archives" over to the chrooted ISO and burn that. Far easier. If this is about creating a perfect copy: clone your disk with `dd`.  Oh and the 2 answers I made used command line to alter an ISO ;-)

Comment: Here is a starter: http://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu Community Help Wiki has an article on creating a bootable ISO image from an installed system. It appears to use only command-line tools (no GUI).

There are too many steps to list here, so I'll just include the link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall