# How to load docker image from a kickstart or preseed file?

Tags: preseed, docker, custom-distributions, kickstart, custom-installer

I want to create customized ubuntu iso with docker engine installed. I also want to load some docker images in it.

Docker Engine is installed.

I could save docker image using `docker save` command. But I couldn't load during installtion.

My sample kickstart file:

```
%post --nochroot

mkdir /target/usr/share/my-docker-imgs
cp -rf /cdrom/pool/extras/sample.tar /target/usr/share/my-docker-imgs
%end

%post
#server docker status // It shows docker is not running in log file. I also tried to start it hear.

docker load -i /usr/share/my-docker-imgs/sample.tar  //Log: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
%end
```

Also Tried in seed file:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string in-target docker load -i /usr/share/my-docker-imgs/sample.tar;
```

It through error code 127 during installation.

I referenced : [custom ubuntu iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found docker is not started on post installation. Even `/var/lib/docker` directory is not yet created during post installation process.

**Step 1:**  Refere [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154305/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another/41276481#41276481), to export the docker images. You have single file called `docker-images.tar`. Copy it over `pool/extras` directory.

**Step 2:**  `In the preseed/ks-myiso.cfg file,`

```
%post --nochroot

cp -r /cdrom/pool/extras/docker-images.tar /target/usr/share/

%end

%post

mkdir -p /var/lib/docker
tar -xvf /usr/share/naanal_pkgs/docker_images.tar -C /var/lib/docker    

%end
```

Note: I faced some problem while I directly extract tar file from cdrom. If you don't find any issue on this you can directly untar docker-images.tar file without copying it.