# User not recognized in custom install CD using kickstart/kickseed

Tags: preseed, kickstart

I attempted to create a custom ubuntu installer (based on server edition) like:

[How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)

and:

[How to create a Customized Ubuntu Server ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso)

but it failed miserably.

The `txt.cfg` looks like this:

```
label customized
  menu label ^Install customized Ubuntu
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet ks=cdrom:/preseed/custom.cfg ---
```

The `custom.seed` file is a copy of the `ubuntu.seed` and the `custom.cfg` contains among others:

```
#Initial user
user me --fullname "Me" --password secret
```

During the installation process, everything appears to be fine, and I'm even prompted whether I'm sure to use a weak password. After the install finishes and reboots, I'm however unable to login as "me". ...and it's a not a typo, I triple checked it and tried many times. I searched many hours what could be the problem but couldn't find anything.

What's going on?

PS: I tried with the encrypted password option and without!

Comment: Does "Me"≠"me" make a difference?

Comment: @M.Becerra nope