# Problems installing ubuntu from a remastersys created ISO

Tags: 14.04, remastersys

Im trying to create a installable ISO of an existing Ubuntu Server 14.04. For the purpose I tried to use remastersys, pinguybuilder and linux respin all with the same result.

The problems comes when I start the machine, tried both in vbox and a computer, if I click the install option the machine starts but no option to install appears, the system starts as a live distribution. The computer is generated correctly, all files and configuration is preserved, but cant install in the hard-drive.

I tried to use remastersys in different ways, using the commands "remastersys dist", "remastersys dist cdfs" and then "remastersys dist iso custm-iso.iso" and also "remastersys backup". Always I get the same result, no chance to install the iso in a drive.

Comment: Why not do it manually? I made this  http://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso and applied it more than 10 times.

Comment: I saw this solution, but I understand that this solution lets you modify a existing distribution. What a want to do is to create a distribution from an existing ubuntu server, it means, create a distribution replicating the filesystem of a an already installed ubuntu server.

Remastersys allows you to do this, I already created an ubuntu server as a clone of an existing server and ran it in virtualbox as a livecd the problems is I cant install it.

Comment: `dd` is great for cloning, however you'd have to deal with resolving ip address issues, etc. I don't see how else you would replicate an entire file system though. `rsync` can be used to duplicate information more selectively. Honestly, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Your question indicates that you've settled on a solution which isn't performing as desired. Perhaps if you were to share exactly what you want to do it would help us help you (even if the answer is you can't do that)

Comment: The purpose is to create an iso of a working server to install it in another machine. Cloning the hard drive is not the desired solution as the iso needs to be ported to different hardware and environment. I need to create an installable distribution with the contents of the machine. This can be done with tools like SuseStudio or systemback. However, in this case needs to be done in a non-suse machine with no graphical desktop. So remastersys and forks is the only solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the DMDc installer, which created Frannoe for distribution: 
http: //www.dmdcosillas.org

This installer is based on Remastersys. It is specific to the DMDc distributions DKDC and DxDC. If you want to use it in your distribution you will have to modify it and adapt it.