# How to edit an iso image and recompress a extracted folder back to a bootable iso?

Tags: boot, system-installation, iso

I have an `.iso` image of Ubuntu 16.04. I wanted to edit it by adding some more packages so I extracted it, and then when I try to compress it again to `.iso` image it doesn't boot.

Even though when I extract it and re-compress back to `.iso` with no edits it still doesn't boot in VirtualBox, USB nor DVD.

How can I make it bootable again ?

Comment: What do you mean by "extracted it"? The correct way is to use squashfs and mount it.  See for instance:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso/409651#409651 It includes recreating the ISO (is done with mkisofs)

Comment: i mean uncompress iso image to folder so i can edit it. And then convert the folder back to iso again.

Comment: FYI, ISOs are uncompressed.

Comment: I use thunar file manager and one of compressions options are ISO. So i guess this is uncorrect method.

Comment: @samjbr It's grouped with compression formats more for convenience than technical correctness. They're all archive formats, at least.

Comment: How the technical correctness be used for a beginner ?