# Deb package Installation Error while installing customized ubuntu server iso

Tags: 14.04, server, package-management, iso, deb

While I am trying to install a deb package embedded inside customized Ubuntu server ISO file, I get an installation error saying:

> An installation step failed. You can try to run the failing item again from the menu or skip it and choose something else. The failing step is: Select and install software.

When I exclude the deb package everything seems to work perfectly. At first I thought it was a dependency problem but I am certain all the dependencies copied to the ISO file. Another opinion I got is maybe there is something wrong with deb package while creating it but it could be installed on command line without any problem. The steps I followed [How to create a Customized Ubuntu Server ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso) while creating the ISO file.

Maybe am I missing something ?

EDIT: I think system tries to download the package from system repositories then says *"Unable to locate the package"* and doesn't recognize the folder `extras` I created so it can not find the package.

But I solved it in a different way. I created a local repository then installed packages and everything worked perfectly yet still don't know how to solve the first problem. The steps I followed:

1. First I created necessary folders

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/Downloads/newIso/dists/stable/extras/binary-i386 ~/Downloads/newIso/pool/extras/
   sudo cp ~/Downloads/*.deb newIso/pool/extras/
   ```
2. Then created `Packages.gz` which includes info of packages

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/newIso
   sudo apt-ftparchive packages ./pool/extras/ | gzip -c > ./dists/stable/extras/binary-i386/Packages.gz
   cd ~/Downloads/
   ```
3. And added following line to the pre-seed file:

   ```
   d-i pkgsel/include string PACKAGE_NAME
   ```

   BTW I also tried without changing the pre-seed file just to see if the system searches `extras/binary-i386` folder for packages.
4. Finally I created the ISO file:

   ```
   sudo mkisofs -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -z -iso-level 4 -c isolinux/isolinux.cat -o ./ubuntu-14.04-myowninstall-amd64.iso -joliet-long newIso/
   ```
5. After installing system packages the installer says:

   > An installation step is failed …

   After I looked at the debug logs, I saw:

   > Unable to locate PACKAGE_NAME

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Let me rephrase that: What's the *exact* command in question that you issued and what's its *entire, verbatim* output?

Comment: I edited question hope that would be enough info.

Comment: Have you tried `dpkg-scanpackages -m base_image/yourpackagefolder/ /dev/null | gzip -9c > base_image/yourpackagefolder/Packages.gz`? It should make the iso find your package.

Comment: Yes I have, but I used apt-ftparchives command instead of  dpkg-scanpackages , I will try dpkg-scanpackages too and inform you about the result