# How do I put OEM installation into live usb?

Tags: live-usb, iso, custom-distributions, oem

What I want to do is customize Ubuntu through OEM, then, flash said OEM installation to an ISO so I can install it on others computers without having to redo my customization later. (also so that other can download said ISO and install it with my customizations)

Comment: You can't download an OEM. Those are created by 3rd party and you only get a restore partition. Why does it need to be OEM? I myself would download a server install and add packages you want. https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso/409651#409651 allows for a base server install, you can add any desktop you want and put files on users desktop.

Comment: Please do not post duplicates.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The post that you refer to is by the same OP. it has no answers and is likely of no use to the OP. The comments in that post also offer no help.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron The pintnis the dupe is from the OP. Just because you don't get the answer you'd like doesn't mean you should post the same question again.

Comment: @Spaceguy99: Have you tried the "OEM install (for manufacturers)" on the installer drive? If so where is it failing for you?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: I understand your concerns. What should the OP do? Edit his original question, ask an upgraded question, ask on Ubuntu Forums, or just give up?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Yes, I think they should consider what has been suggested in comments and find a doable alternative.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron And although the installer has the option for "OEM" (it always did as far as I can remember and it was always possible to do the same by installing something similar to Windows' sysprep) that is NOT what the OP is asking for. OP apparently wants a modified installation ISO. Imagining the modified system is doable but doing what they want is only for very skilled devs.

Answer (score 0):

### OEM INSTALL

There is an overview for Ubuntu OEM INSTALL:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

The OEM install sets up a computer so that first use the new owner will be taken to the system setup wizard where he will be able to set his location, keyboard layout, user name etc.

The OEM install does not create a custom ISO.

### OEM INSTALL - IMAGE

One method of using OEM install to create a custom installer that might work for you:

- Use "OEM install (for manufacturers)" on the installer drive to create your customized OEM install on a spare USB.
- Start the OEM USB and install your extra programs and modify the setup as you wish, however home directory stuff like wallpaper and Bookmarks does not stick.
- Create an image, (.img), of the USB using dd or similar.

  dd if=/dev/sdx of=Spaceguy99.img

Where sdx is the OEM drive.

**OS Installation**

- Use mkusb in Linux or Win32Diskimager in Windows to overwright your target disk with the extracted image.
- When booting the target disk for the first time the user will be prompted for a new Location, Name, Password, etc.

This method is not as neat as building a custom ISO but is a lot simpler and gets the job done.

Note that an image file can be compressed but must be decompressed to be written. Suggest using the smallest Target drive that fit the data, A 32GB drive takes a long time to dd and write.

**Isorespin** may be a good choice for modifying ISOs

http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2018/05/introducing-isorespinsh-templates.html