# What is the difference between a live image ubuntu iso and complete iso

Tags: system-installation, system

There is definitely a size difference in both live-server image and normal complete image. Also the complete image with all the repositories is not available on the official site also?

Comment: Please define what do you mean by "complete image". And if it is not available on the official site, where did you get it from (link)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) and [How to create a Customized Ubuntu Server ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso/)?

Comment: The *live* server image is capable of running in a *live* environment, though it requires greater resources (RAM especially) to operate, than the non-live requires. For some releases a non-live option was provided for low-RAM environments, ie. those incapable of running a *live* system plus have the 1GB required for the installer program.  The end result was identical; the non-live ISO just allowed installation on a lower RAM machine than *live* allowed for.

Comment: There is no iso file with all [available] packages included. If you want to install a custom set of program packages, you can create a custom iso file. If your target computers are fairly similar, an alternative is to [use the OEM feature](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), create a master installed system in one computer and install cloned copies to the other computers. When this is an option, it is much easier than to create a custom iso file.

Answer (score 2):

If you got an image that is not on the official site, then it's not an official image, and nobody has any chance to know what it is, unless you provide a link.

I would strongly advice against installing Ubuntu from any other source than images found on the official website.

Comment: I am saying on the official site live-server image is there my purpose is download a complete ISO file with all the packages included automate its installlation process to deploy it to multiple systems

Comment: It sounds like you want to customize the ISO image - there are several existing Q&A's on this.